# Does Terraform execute parallely in multi-cloud deployments?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create a VMs in different cloud provider from a single Terraform script e.g. GCP, AWS, Azure using Terraform.
So, I wanted to know that, will Terraform make the VM instances in parallel in all public clouds?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform builds a directed, acyclical graphic (also referred to as a DAG) to understand the dependencies between things. If something isn't dependent on something else then it will execute it in parallel up to the number specified by the [`-parallelism` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n) which defaults to 10.

If things are completely separate across multiple providers (you're just creating the same stack in *n* cloud providers) then it will be comfortably parallel across those stacks.

However, I'd recommend against applying multiple environments/cloud providers at the same time like this because of blast radius issues and in general erring towards minimising how much changes in one operation.

If you have cross provider dependencies then Terraform is great for handling this but it still relies on building that DAG so it can understand your dependencies.

For example you might want to create an instance in GCP and use DNS to resolve the IP address but use AWS' Route53 for all your DNS. For this you could use something like this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  // Local SSD disk
  scratch_disk {
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  metadata = {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "echo hi > /test.txt"

  service_account {
    scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
  }
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name = "example.com."
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id}"
  name    = "www.${data.aws_route53_zone.example.name}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${google_compute_instance.test.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"]
}
```

This would build a graph that has the `aws_route53_record.www` depending on both the `data.aws_route53_zone.example` data source and also the `google_compute_instance.test` resource so Terraform knows that both of these need to complete before it can start work on the Route53 record.